# Efficiency: singleton vs factory

Tags: android, design-patterns

Working with android device, I am implementing my own logging class. It has two parts: file and console logging. For file I have used a factory pattern to ensure that every instance has its own file and enforce mutual exclusion. Console logging doesn't have this problems, and I have the methods ready to make their own factory, but then I started considering about memory.

Performance-wise, is it better to have one lingering static console logger and return it, or allow the programmer to have as many as they want, and let them be cleaned by the garbage collector?

Comment: I think Singleton would be better. But couldn't you just use `public static` methods?

Comment: Should be a singleton but why roll your own?

Comment: @shkschneider No because both loggers inherit from an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that keeping a singleton instance is going to be more efficient. Creation and destruction of the objects is going to make the factory approach slightly slower.